# How to put delay on .append for my animation text in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, animation

Hi I am having animation that will slide text up but it is too fast, I want to slow it down.
I am using .pend to have the the animation working.

here is my code, I just want to slow down the append thing

$splitByWords.each(function () {

```
var $this = $(this);
var words = $this.text().split(" ");
$this.empty();
var space;
$.each(words, function (i, v) {
  space = v === ' ' ? ' class="space"' : '';

    $this.append("<span" + space + ">" + v + "</span>";


});
```

});

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap a `setTimeout` around it. Note that increasing the timeout is important, otherwise, the words will appear with delay but all at once. As I understand it, you want one word to appear after another with a short delay between each.

Also note, that the statement creating the `space` variable in your code is not used, so I omit it here. You define `words` as splitting some text by spaces. So, the array of words will not contain any single space character. Hence, the ternary operator used to assign to `space` always returns the same.

```js
var $this = $(this);
const words = $this.text().split(" ");
$this.empty();
$.each(words, function (i, v) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $this.append(`<span>${v}</span>`);
  }, i * 100);
});
```